# Dealing with file permission on NFS NAS with multiple servers

Tags: linux, nfs, network-attached-storage, permissions, filer

This may sound dumb but I am asking because I think there is an easy solution to this before I scratch my head too much.

We have a SAN with a filer on top that provides NFS share for other servers.

ServerA and ServerB have this share NFS mounted with no_root_squash. 
ServerA has userA on it which owns a folderA on NFS NAS.
ServerB has UserB on it which needs write access to folderA.

is the solution to create a NFSUsers group on all servers and chgrp the folder to that or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution might work but the best method (IMHO) to handle this kind of problem is to create a central user database, be it with NIS/YP, LDAP/AD or some other method.

You could then create groups for sharing that are automatically synced on all affected servers.